# Can Mercurial hg glog be restricted to branches

Tags: mercurial, dvcs

Mercurial log allows you to restrict the query to branches:

hg log -b default

But Mercurial glog does not

hg glog -b default => error message

Is there any way to filter glog like this?  Perhaps an ugly Perl or Python script operating on

hg glog --style xml | perl UglyScript

I am looking at revsets, but haven't figured out a way to do this.

--

By the way, why I want to do this, in case there is a better way: my teammates think I am too verbose and do too many fine grain commits, so I want to give them a way to filter out my commit messages from hg glog. I'll put my stuff on a branch. I'd like them to be able to ignore my branch (or tag, or label, or ...)  (At the moment I am editing history at every push to the project masrter, which is wasteful and fragile.)

"hg log -b" is fine, but really want glog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah ha! I found part of the answer:

hg glog –r ‘branch(default)’

hg log –r ‘branch(default)’
works just like
hg log –b default

except that they are in opposite order.
(Unlike http://markmail.org/thread/43yvy7mljdfgp75h which says that -b x == -r 'branch(x)'

hg log –r ‘reverse(branch(default))’

revsets rule!